# How to avoid "access web content" dialog in MS power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm accessing an xml rest web-service. In the "Access web content" dialog I use "Windows" and "use my current credentials". Works absolutely fine. But when my colleges are trying to update the data, they are asked for how they want to access data. They have to open Power Query Editor and find this dialog to do that. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Are you able to connect anonymously or does the service require credentials?

Comment: It requries windows credentials. Like trusted connections.

Comment: Data originates from Lotus Notes. Web-services is on an intra-net.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure if this is feasible since you're essentially wanting to dictate the security setting for another user. I could be wrong but this might just be a necessary one-time configuration for each user.

Comment: In M the request is formulated like this:
Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://app-service.net/rest/datapoint/123456/dataset1"))
If users enter the path in a browser, they will always be validated by their Windows Credentials and never be asked for additional information.